# jQuery "On Blur" selector not working when looking for an attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, blur

I do not understand why I can use

```
$(document).on('blur', '.required', function() {});
```

But I am unable to use

```
$(document).on('blur', '[required="yes"]', function() {});
```

On this type of element

```
<input type="text" class="required" name="myelement" required="yes" />
```

The same selector looking for `[required="yes"]` works if I want to make a change to the element, such as

```
$('[required="yes"]').val('New Val');
```

But it does not for the on blur event.  I do not feel like adding a `required` class to all of my elements.

Comment: "yes" is not a valid value for the required attribute.

Comment: The question seems valid to me, so ima upvote it to bring it back to neutral at least. As JJJ points out, "yes" is not a valid value, if I were to change the selector to `$(document).on('blur', '[required="required"]', function() {});`, it works